# Can't display special characters (umlauts)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, codepages

My startup parameters of progress are

```
-cpstream ibm850
-cpinternal 1252
```

When I execute `MESSAGE rÖÄÜ.`, I get the result

> r

Why the umlauts are not being displayed?

I'm using OpenEdge 10.2B with Archtitect.

**Edit:** If I run this program with the Progress Procedure Editor I get the umlauts displayed. I think I have misconfigured something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Which platform and in case of Unix which terminal settings do you use?

Comment: Win7 x64 @MikeFechner

Comment: Where have you set your startup paramerers? In the project? Somewhere else?

Comment: @Jensd Startup parameters are set in a .pf-file which is referenced in "Preferences/OpenEdge Architect/Startup".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Run configurations" you can also set startup parameters. The error lied there.